# Can you redirect monit alerts to MQTT

Tags: monit

Can you redirect monit alerts to MQTT?

The work-around with `exec mosquitto_pub -h .. -u .. -P .. -t .. -m ..` is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways:

#### 1. Helperscript

Where you include all the config to an executable file like `/opt/monit_helper/send-mqtt.sh` with your `mosquitto_pub` command in it.

```
#!/bin/bash
mosquitto_pub -h .. -u .. -P .. -t "${2:-monitoring}" -m "$1"
```

So you can use `exec /opt/monit_helper/send-mqtt.sh "my cool message"` or `/opt/monit_helper/send-mqtt.sh "my even cooler message" "my awesome topic"` (topic falls back to `monitoring` if not set manually).

#### 2. Use E-Mail (and/or fake it)

Since I was not happy with only the `exec` option, but wanted all the info monit is sending by e-mail I wrote a fake SMTP-Server that can handle the e-mails sent by monit and runs whatever you want it to run.

You'll find it at https://github.com/boppy/nitmo.fakesmtp - It basically is just a bash script. See the `.sh` file, lines 14..45 for config ideas/examples.

Comment: Thanks, good idea to redirect email to a script.
For postfix it works like this: https://serverfault.com/a/881179/109262